# Magento: Add the same product to cart several times

Tags: php, magento

I try to add product twice (or several times) to cart, with different attributes values.

I have read this post : [Magento: add product twice to cart, with different attributes!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063460/magento-add-product-twice-to-cart-with-different-attributes)

but I haven't found a good clear answer there.

I have overriden the controller "app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php" but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: What is your actual question? I can't see one here or a precise problem.

Comment: I want to add the same product (same SKU) twice, for example with lenses one time with an attribute value right, and one other time with an attribute value left. My problem is that the 2 products with different attributes count as the same product, and I want to see them in cart as 2 different products. Help !!

Comment: Why would you want them separate if they have the same stock code? They are the same item if that is the case?

Comment: It's not exactly the same product, in my case the user have to specify wich motiv can he add to the basic product and he can can different variations of this basic product with differents motives to the cart...

Answer (score 1):

Add the lens eye (left or right) as a custom option to the product in the backend.

Magento uses product custom options as one of the discriminators between shopping cart items when trying to determine whether to add a quantity to an existing cart item or create a new one.

The user can choose LEFT or RIGHT from the frontend and Magento will show it in the cart as 2 separate products, but deduct the stock from the same physical product.

Answer (score 0):

The two product pair if you are trying to add should still have some different attribute... if it is lenses or shoes or gloves add an attribute to tell if it is left or right to distinguish... or else the two products you add count as the same product with quantity 2.

Answer (score 0):

Go to class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
and search for the method getItemByProduct($product) and make it return false all the time.
Be careful, this might interfere with the minimum & maximum allowed in cart for products.

Comment: Bad advice because this will break adding a quantity to an existing item in the cart (when it is the same option and same item).

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom options, change the option value programmaticly